# How can we do count repeating street addresses, and plot the results in Folium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, geospatial, folium

I'm testing this code.  First I count records with the same street address.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
import folium
from folium import plugins


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\lat_lon.csv')

# count in new column of same dataframe
df['Count'] = df.groupby('Street')['Street'].transform('count')
print(df.dtypes)
```

Everything up to this point ins fine.  Now, I am trying to prepare this to be plotted in a Jupyter Notebook.  Here's the code that I cam up with.

```
m = df[['latitude', 'longitude', 'Count']].groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).sum().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

That gives me this.

```
[[37.09024, -95.712891, 1.0],
 [40.712346600000004, -73.99634559999998, 1.0],
 [40.71247169999999, -73.9998602, 5.0],
 [40.7127474, -73.99936509999998, 5.0],
 [40.7128109, -73.99474409999998, 25.0],
 [40.71281889999999, -73.9954473, 1.0],
 [40.7128448, -74.00899229999999, 11449.0],
 [40.712933500000005, -74.00089059999998, 3.0],
etc., etc., etc.
```

Finally, I am trying to plot the results in Folium.  I thought it should be something like this.

```
folium.Marker(m)
```

That throws and error.

Or, something like this.

```
HeatMap(m).add_to(m)
```

I think this is pretty close, but something is definitely off here. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research on this thing and got this code (below) to work.

```
def generateBaseMap(default_location=[40.693943, -73.985880], default_zoom_start=12):
    base_map = folium.Map(location=default_location, control_scale=True, zoom_start=default_zoom_start)
    return base_map

base_map = generateBaseMap
base_map

from folium.plugins import HeatMap
base_map = generateBaseMap()
HeatMap(data=df_copy[['latitude', 'longitude', 'Count']].groupby(['atitude', 'longitude']).sum().reset_index().values.tolist(), radius=8, max_zoom=13).add_to(base_map)

base_map.add_child(folium.ClickForMarker(popup='Potential Location'))
```

[image]

You can even do some really cool stuff with animated heat maps that change dynamically over time.

```
# First, we need to create a list containing the list of values that we wish to plot, grouped by the 
# dimension that we want to use (in this example we will be using hour as the dimension).

df_hour_list = []
for hour in df_copy.hour.sort_values().unique():
    df_hour_list.append(df_copy.loc[df_copy.hour == hour, ['latitude', 'longitude', 'Count']].groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).sum().reset_index().values.tolist())
    

# After we generated the data that we will use for the HeatMapWithTime class method, we can call the 
# method and add it to our map.

from folium.plugins import HeatMapWithTime
base_map = generateBaseMap(default_zoom_start=11)
HeatMapWithTime(df_hour_list, radius=5, gradient={0.2: 'blue', 0.4: 'lime', 0.6: 'orange', 1: 'red'}, min_opacity=0.5, max_opacity=0.8, use_local_extrema=True).add_to(base_map)
base_map
```

[image]